# Map Scale Wonky

Tags: qgis-3, layouts, printing

I'm working in QGIS LTR 3.28 on Mac.  In Print Layout, I cannot seem to get a scale to show up. I tried six times to insert a scale, and when I exported to .pdf, I get this (see attached). Cannot seem to click on any of the failed attempts at inserting a scale in the Print Layout to edit or delete.

[image]

[Test Map with Scale Problems](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tjq5qgkdykuxxdo/Zoning%20Map%20Test.pdf?dl=0)

Comment: Have you enabled the Items Panel, and can you select the Scalebar in the Items Panel?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works